# Как использовать разные прокси с авторизацией с Selenium на python в Chrome?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy

Задача такая: нужно переходить по ссылке в многопотоке и использовать каждый раз рандомные прокси из файла (формат прокси - host:port:username:password). Видел вариант с использованием js и json файлами, которые потом объединяются в zip файл, который передается как аргумент. Сначала я подумал, что можно просто каждую итерацию переписывать файлы js\json и менять там прокси. Но есть проблема - если запускать программу в многопотоке, то один файл будет перезаписываться разными потоками из-за чего будут возникать ошибки.
Есть какие-то варианты решить эту задачу\проблему?

P.S. Есть вариант написать костыль:
через pyautogui постоянно авторизовываться - вводить логин - пароль от прокси. Не знаю насколько плохо это будет работать)